# How do use fgets to find if this line exists in .csv file? (C)

Tags: c, csv

Hi I'm tyring to use fgets in a C program to see whether or not a name exists in a line in a .csv file. If it does, then it saves it in an array then returns it. Right now, it saves everything line from the .csv file and I'm not sure why.

C file:

```
void FindRecord(char *filename, char *name, char record[]) {

    char *temp = record; //temp save record

    FILE *q = fopen(filename, "r"); //check that ths inputed .csv file exists
    if (q == NULL ) { //if it doesn't, then print error message and exit
        printf("This .csv does not exist");
        exit(1); //terminate with error message
    }

    while(!feof(q)) { //while I'm not at the end of the file
        fgets(temp, 1000, q); //Reads a line @ a time
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            if(temp[i] == *name) {
                record[i] = temp[i];
                name++;
            }
        }
        printf("%s", record);
    }
    fclose(q);   
}
```

.csv file:

```
Kevin, 123-456-7890
Sally, 213-435-6479
Megan, 415-336-8790
```

Right now whats happening when I run the program is that it returns the 3 lines. I want iso that if `*name` points to the name `"Kevin"` and it comes with temp, it'll just return: `Kevin, 123-456-7890`

Comment: Please read [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26557243/1983495).

Comment: Why 1000 in `fgets(temp, 1000, q)`?  `record` is not shown to be that big.  Need to see the calling code.

Comment: `record` and `temp` point to the same memory so `record[i] = temp[i]` is useless. `fgets(temp, 1000, q);` loads whatever from the file into `temp`, and also `record`.

Comment: If this is like the 3 other versions of the same question asked recently, you are also failing to remove the trailing `'\n'` from `name` before passing it to your function (just a guess as to another complicating factor) Generally, you will also want to open the file in the calling function and pass a `FILE *` pointer as a parameter to your function. If this is the only function that reads from the file, it doesn't matter, it is just a non-standard way of doing it (especially with a return type `void` that can provide no indication of success/failure in return ).

Comment: How do you know your `fgets()` call actually works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Right now whats happening when I run the program is that it returns the 3 lines.

I don't see how that's possible.  You have only one array in which to return a result.  I could believe that your code *prints* all three lines, but it will *return* only the last.

> I want iso that if `*name` points to the name `"Kevin"` and it comes with `temp`, it'll just return: `Kevin, 123-456-7890`

Well, your code has several problems in that regard.  Among the most significant are:

- Although it performs some character-by-character comparisons, it has no code anywhere to reject lines that fail to match.
- It sets `temp` to point to the same array as `record`, and then reads each line into that array.  This will overwrite that array even in the event that no match is found, and if a match is found on a line other than the last one read then the actual match will be lost.
- It modifies the `name` pointer as it attempts to match, with no mechanism for resetting it in the event of a partial match.
- When trying to match the name, it blithely scans past the `,` delimiter in the input line and, if it comes to them, the string terminators in the name and the input string.
- [`while (!feof(file))` is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26557243/1983495).